# Failed to fetch locations error message when trying to create a new web app in azure openai studio

Tags: azure, web-applications, openai-api

In azure openai studio, after creating model, I'm trying to deploy model to a new web application and getting a "Failed to fetch locations" error message, and a message which says "Request failed with status code 404"

I'm getting this message after I select my Subscription.  My Azure Resource group has a location, so not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Register the Microsoft.Web resource provider in the subscription blade and that will allow the app to retrieve locations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).